# Viviani's Curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential

What is the parametric equation of the curve obtained by the intersection of the sphere 
                               $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$$
and the cylinder 
                            $$x^2 + y^2 = ay.$$

I do not have any idea how to solve it
 Please help

Comment: $x^2+y^2=az$ is not the equation of a cylinder.

Comment: @Aretino I corrected it

Comment: 3 questions in one hour, don't you think you should take time to breath...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $x,y$ from the cylinder, which is a circle of radius $\frac a2$ centered at $\left(0,\frac a2\right)$, then compute the $z$ from the sphere:
$$
\begin{align}
x&=\frac a2\sin(\theta)\\
y&=\frac a2-\frac a2\cos(\theta)\\[3pt]
z&=a\cos(\theta/2)
\end{align}
$$
for $\theta\in[0,4\pi]$.

Comment: I do not understand can you please elaborate

Comment: Circle of radius $\frac a2$ centered at $\left(0,\frac a2\right)$ $\left(\text{from }x^2+y^2=ay\right)$: $$\begin{align} x&=\frac a2\sin(\theta)\\ y&=\frac a2-\frac a2\cos(\theta) \end{align}$$ Then figure out $z$ from $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$.